# I have a sensory details chart that needs to be filled out soon!

Tags: single-word-requests, sentence

Can anyone give me a few college level words, or a sentence,  to describe what the rural outdoors taste like? The setting is a large terrain with cows, goats, horses, and a big lake. Could there be somthing in the air that you could taste while outside in this setting?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this post is doomed and will soon disappear.  The guardians of this site think that if they do your homework for you the whole Nation will turn into mindless fools and sink into a morass of slovenliness.  But don't take it badly. Just be quick to try the links.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43281/the-lake-isle-of-innisfree); or else this advertisement for [UK National Trust](https://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/countryside). Are there any National Parks, Holiday Cottages, Boot and tent makers you can think of who try to describe the countryside in purple prose?